# Acceptable profile photos

Tags: discussion

I notice that this male [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6591890/panjul) has a bare-chested profile picture.

It occurs to me that Stack Overflow probably has guidelines on what constitutes acceptable profile photos.  Or perhaps not.

My real question is:  Does Stack Overflow allow bare-chested photos of women for profile photos?  If not, should we allow bare-chested photos of men?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. It doesn't interfere with the sites goal or users' ability to answer or ask effectively. It really depends, but if it doesn't impede users, then it's harmless

Comment: Seems like a case by case basis thing to me. If you see something in a user profile that you find offensive, flag one of the users posts for moderator intervention detailing what content you find offensive and why. Most moderators will not moderate avatars unless they are attacking a person or group of people, or are blatantly offensive.

Comment: Gordon we know you are really a Fabio sql type

Comment: @Drew . . . Sigh.  There are people who might be offended by such things and not return to the site, rather than mentioning anything.  I truly understand the difficulty of trying to be offense-free; that profile picture just led me to ask the question.

Comment: lol, facebook is blocked at my work so the images from there (or to be percise `https://graph.facebook.com`) are blocked as well. not like i expect anything meaningful from a facebook avatar (and hardly ever is it a cute anime pic for me to download)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Don't you think it would turn the linked user away if the site forced him to change his picture because someone thought it was offensive? Everyone is going to be offended at something, but it doesn't mean we have to fit everyone's needs to not offend everyone. Do what's right for the greater majority. I see no problem

Comment: Maybe the better question would be here, where exactly is the line drawn between acceptable and unacceptable profile pictures. To not just ask about bare chest photos.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking someone won't return to the site because 1 in 10k pictures depicts a guy that doesn't eat the crap I eat. Our peers have problems to solve and that is why they are here.

Comment: @Rizier123: But that's something that *has to be* done on a case-by-case basis. You can't just hand down a blanket rule like that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For many (but not all!) cultures, bare-chested women make people more uncomfortable than bare-chested men. While this does seem to be a double standard, we can avoid the problem by being a bit pragmatic. As [Jay said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/1438):

> Our tolerance in different areas has a lot to do with how much they're in *your* space on the site, vs. the *public* space. Posts are very public, shared resources. Your username and avatar are (obviously) *more* about you, but they appear anywhere you post, so they're pretty public. Your about me is visible to the public, but in your little public corner of the site, so we're a bit more liberal:
>
> [image]

The avatar you linked to seems to me somewhere between "Casual" and "Zardoz", while a bare-chested woman would be effectively naked for many users (including myself). Again, this has little to do with logic and more to do with cultural norms.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/404

Comment: @BhargavRao Not there anymore.

Comment: Uh, oh @WelcometoStackOverflow, looks like that's one of the victims of the welcoming saga (could have blamed the new designs, but it hasn't been rolled out to Stack Apps). Now we need to search the tweet which triggered that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a hard line definition on what exactly is and isn't allowed for profile pictures is needed here. There are only very few cases in which users take offense can be handled on a case-by-case basis.

While I wouldn't have a problem with someone having a bare-chested woman as profile picture, more people may. Its worth keeping the demographics of this site in mind.

I would say that we should not put any "hard" limits on what you can and cannot put in a profile picture in place. We're mostly grown ups here, and we can sensibly decide by case.

Comment: I'm starting to doubt that we're mostly grown ups around here.  And that's *me* saying this.