# Is it ok to have links on how to create sock puppets and gain rep fraudulently in user profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

The question really is that simple. There's a lot of discussion about what is allowed in user profiles, but nothing that actually covers this. I removed a link to a GitHub repository with code to run, to create sock puppet accounts and instructions on how to increase reputation points and what to do to gain reputation points.

Although many people can work these things out for themselves, it still gives some people the tools they may not have. Linking it on the site it's intended to harm, to me, is not a good idea.

Thoughts?

Related:

- *[Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles)*
- *[Is it acceptable to insult god in a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile)*
- *[Acceptable profile photos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334578/acceptable-profile-photos)*

Comment: Could you post an anonymized version of the profile text? Or is it just the link to the repo? Imho, instructions and links to do something that is illegal, against the CoC or against the site rules should be removed.

Comment: @BDL it was a link to the repo. I'm not keen on linking it to the actual user profile or repo, as it will be a goto way to find it for people wanting to mess with the site.

Comment: Since such things directly subvert the site's principles, I would say it isn't ok.

Comment: The less is said/documented about it the better.  This just doesn't need a hard rule carved out on a stone tablet but can be entirely left to a moderator's judgement.  If anybody complains about it then the mod can direct them to meta to make their case.  Woof, imagine the spectacle.

Comment: @HansPassant Ironically, this is in response to a flag and a subsequent complaint. Could you believe it? Instead I brought it to meta to save the person linking said repo into a meta post.

Comment: (Good to see you back, with your diamond icon)

Comment: I'm somewhat curious now as to what that github is and if there's anything I can extract from their recommendations for sock puppet owners to find some more of them ....

Comment: @Magisch Reverse engineer, and use it to strengthen the vote fraud script.  "Your workarounds have made us stronger!"

Comment: I always had the impression that most of the photos of 1rep accounts seem to be google-stock things - probably some generic list of usa/canada/german universities and "I am student at {x}" with a random.choice(piclist) script. Would'nt mind to take a look at the repository myself though

Comment: Thanks for creating this post. I wish you had pinged me about it, but thanks for creating it. Now it's time to for me to lose some useless meta rep.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 There's no such thing as meta rep, and be aware that I am unhappy that you have done this. At the very _least_ you should've told SE staff so they could proof the system against your code. The techniques are known, and there's no way to easily protect against them without compromising the system for everyone else.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 ah OK meta rep got abolished at some point? That's good. BTW, I had posted this long ago on StackApps where it got deleted, I'm pretty sure they were alerted then. In any case, certainly SO devs are aware of such matters before my script. Instead of hiding it, we should acknowledge it and search for a real algorithmic solution.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Any algorithmic solution would harm real users. Unless you mean added heuristics, in which case that'd harm real users behind NATs.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Removing content from user profiles that describe how to circumvent or cheat the site (and would, when noticed, lead to suspensions or account deletions) is fine.

Same goes for content that is illegal or against the CoC.

Comment: I would argue on illegal, as we have to know the scope. People using Chinesse banned words  came to my mind.

Comment: @xdtTransform if by "Chinese banned words" you're referring to words/phrases that are alleged to trigger internet bans for anyone trying to access them from within the great firewall, I'd argue they're every bit as abusive as a tirade of profanity and should result in the user being smacked down just as hard by moderation.

Comment: @DanNeely: Already discussed in [Are political profiles that could possibly affect the participations of other users allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298950/are-political-profiles-that-could-possibly-affect-the-participations-of-other-us?rq=1)

Comment: @xdtTransform Good point. I've come across a fair few profiles (mostly by higher-rep users) protesting against the Communist Party of China, which would likely be illegal or have severe social repercussions if viewed or expressed within the PRC. For example, would I be violating the CoC if I appended 臺灣不在中國 (Taiwan is not a part of China) to my display name, even though it's perfectly valid for me to express in my country of residence?

Comment: For the record I know that point has been discussed to death in the link BDL posted, but just stating that the definition of "illegal" can vary wildly outside of the "obvious" global laws

Comment: Guys, are you looking for the definition of "illegal" for the purpose of this site? I can help ! Just scroll down, click on link named "Legal", Ctrl-F, type "jurisdiction", Enter, here we are: "comply with the obligations set forth in these Public Network Terms, and to the extent that use of the public Network does not conflict with the applicable laws, rules and regulations of the user’s jurisdiction. Stack Overflow reserves the right to refuse, suspend or terminate your access to the public Network if it determines, in its sole discretion ...". It's that simple.

Comment: Interesting problem. I would not look upon someone favourably if their profile/ posting signature, etc... contained content that put some schlimazel on a watchlist in a repressive country. Or a free country, for that matter.

Comment: @DanNeely allowing a dictatorship to become technologically advanced and start WW3 might be even more abusive.

Answer (score 27):

There's already established precedent [for posts which do something like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267721/1079354).  I would imagine that the user profile doesn't diverge *too* much from this heuristic.

Since there's **no** material value from showing users how to defraud the Stack Exchange network, its removal is *perfectly* acceptable.

Comment: There is one material value: without transparency, there can be no trust: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381577/is-it-ok-to-have-links-on-how-to-create-sock-puppets-and-gain-rep-fraudulently-i/381635#381635

Comment: Defrauding a system isn't the same as compromising a system.  Also, Stack Overflow's a fairly open book; there's no new exploits to be had in creating tens or hundreds of sock puppets to upvote your content.  All this does is package this process up in something convenient for someone who *really* cares about these unicorn points enough to cheat their way to a few thousand.

Answer (score -20):

**It should be allowed, security by obscurity only makes things worse**

It is a well established principle that trying to secure a system by trying to hide how it works only makes things worse:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle
- [Why is security through obscurity a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea)

If the system is vulnerable to sock puppets, and those puppets are easy to bootstrap and conceal, then it has certainly already been breached by black hats without us knowing it.

Instead of trying to hide the fact that the system is flawed, we should instead improve the post / user rating with a better algorithm, e.g. PageRank-like. This would require sock puppets to vote between themselves to have any weight, and then it would be easier to find and take down entire sock puppet nets in one go.

Without transparency, in particular of the fraud detection algorithms, Stack Overflow reputation will never be truly trustworthy.

Since upvoter data is private, it is not possible for the public to develop such algorithms. Therefore, the only alternative for the public to explore the opaque system is by trying to create the puppets and see if they are caught. White hats will then reveal their actions eventually, while black hats won't.

White hats won't have the patience to set things up and provide a better algorithm as it stands.

**It does not make any difference if such content is banned on Stack Overflow alone**

Any highly ranked Google PageRank GitHub repository will be found by anyone trying  to attack a website.

Black hats are highly specialized at finding sources with the newest exploits, and they certainly know how to Google.

Comment: In reading this answer, I think you are grossly misinterpreting the situation.  There are no exploits being discussed here.

Comment: @Makoto I believe security exploits and vote fraud are exactly analogous.

Comment: I'd argue it's the difference between unethical social engineering and penetration testing.

Comment: To put a finer point to it, the exploit is well-known - a user creates dozens of sock puppets to upvote their content.  This can be detected by moderators and action can be taken against them at scale.  There's no inherent vulnerability in allowing users to create accounts or vote on posts, but there is a ToS violation if you create two or more accounts to interact with one another.  In other words, **the system is as open as it can be.**  The main issue at hand is allowing someone the convenience of automating that process.

Comment: I think you're over-emphasizing the "security through obscurity" aspect of removing this information from a profile.  See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32066/88244) for why removing blatant links to breaking site rules is fine.  It's relying on obscurity as the only defense that is bad, not the removal of ToS breaking content.

Comment: @Makoto if the system makes it possible to users to create accounts such accounts and go undetected, the system is flawed and reputation cannot be trusted. It does not matter if it is a social / algorithmic problem. It cannot be trusted in any case. It should also be considered that this case also has an algorithmic component. Both technical and non-technical attacks are equally unethical.

Comment: My contention is that they're detected...but I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thanks for the link. About ToS: I argue that this point can be improved.

Comment: To be clear. I've looked at your repo and your ethics and I deeply admire you. I just don't think it's ok to put a link to it in your profile. Yes it can be found elsewhere, but that's not SO's concern. I understand your convictions about security through obscurity. Still handing people who otherwise could not manage to do this a way to do it, just doesn't help the site. There will always be challenges in managing a site like this and much of it is based on community participation. Seeing and flagging suspicious activity, on top of any algorithms. So you can decide to help or impede that. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Creating repos on how to circumvent it is actually impeding that. Instead create a repo to help people detect it. The site is what it is, so no matter what your views are on security, it's only helping people break the site rules, not find people breaking them. 
I really wasn't sure how to go about letting you know about this post. I ended up deleting my Twitter account after this (not your fault) and a mod message seemed over the top. I probably should have stalked you and left a comment. I figured you would find it and am glad you did.

Comment: Imho, there is a huge difference between describing a way to cheat the system and providing a tool so that every SkriptKiddy can do it.

Comment: So, how exactly would SO be better off if we all knew ___exactly___ what to avoid when wanting to commit vote fraud?

Comment: @YvetteColomb developing detection is too hard possible for non SO employees because we don't have data about who upvoted whom to test the algorithms.

Comment: @Cerbrus everyone would clearly see that the voting system is broken, and that would force devs to fix it.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功: so you did it the white hat ethical way? First informed the company about your tool, then gave them some time to fix the problem, and only afterwards published the code? Everything else would be just abusive.

Comment: @BDL the problem is obvious, SO devs must already know about it. This was discussed in moderation chat at least once in the past. The only thing left to do is to let the general public see it as well to force their hand.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: and then that vulnerability would be fixed, the fix would be published, and immediatly worked around.  An arms race isn’t productive. If you can avoid giving the opponent the “how to abuse us 101” manual, you’re one step ahead.

Comment: @Cerbrus certain technical measures are very strong and effective, e.g. Google PageRank.

Comment: Note that “Security through obscurity” isn’t relevant here. The secrecy of the vote fraud prevention system isn’t the main method of the system. It’s public knowledge that IP addresses and othe rprofile information is compared. There are just small details that aren’t public information.

Comment: So basically, you want the company to notice your tool because sock puppets take over? It's highly unethical to publish such a tool without informing the company. But, given everything else on your profile, it seems you just like to watch things burn and then claim that you wanted to fix injustice.

Comment: @BDL things must burn for new ones to come up.

Comment: Yea, that's super-villain 101. The only way forward is a hard reset.

Comment: The network has its ways of improved detection beyond what the algorhitm reverses. They have a few layers of protection against vote fraud, and the whole thing is more sophisticated then you think. Also, instead of providing a way people can commit vote fraud, you could focus on finding more vote fraud and making the reputation system more trustworthy yourself. It's not that hard, people are doing it. The algorhitm in exactness isn't public, but if you spend some time with it, you can figure out to catch some of what it misses even from public data and make a positive impact that way. throwi

Comment: ing your hands in the air and going "I guess I'll help burn this system to the ground then so they'll have to make something better" is unhelpful and I'd argue unethical. Instead of trying to harm the site to in some roundabout way allegedly force positive change, how about if you truly care about vote fraud (I'm not mocking that, I do) you help make the defenses more robust and help identify it yourself.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 attempting to force the hand of a site that has so many feature requests on meta that people are growing tired of asking for them is not a constructive way to help the site. It puts more pressure on the people curating the site. There's ways to detect voting fraud, all you're doing is making it more accessible for people to do it and increasing the work load of the community, especially moderators.. Hint hint. It doesn't affect the business. It just helps to erode the site further.

Comment: @YvetteColomb _"It just helps to erode the site further"_ I can't imagine this having any lasting effect. I mean, SO's systems already cover this kind of fraud, not?

Comment: @Cerbrus we need to manually review each issue of potential sock puppets. It requires human eyes to make that decision. Which takes time, as you can imagine to ascertain whether it's a sock or co-workers. Sock accounts are deleted (which invalidates the voting). Targeted voting is reversed. Those and plagiarism are the most time intensive investigations. We have scripts we can run, plus users raise flags.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: But the detection isn't (only) manual.

Comment: @Cerbrus for socks, it's all manual. It's the voting fraud that is picked up automatically and by users observing things that are odd, or running scripts etc. So do the mods.

Comment: _Since upvoter data is private, it is not possible for the public to develop such algorithms._ Personalized upvoter data is private, in aggregate / anonymized form it is not. It's also public who recieves the upvotes. So draw your own conclusions from that.

Comment: If this user left the site and spread the tool through other means, say, twitter:  A) you'd have no recourse to stop him, and B) This "problem" would still exist. So now you have a disgruntled user motivated by spite with a "weapon" that can be easily spread. I agree with Ciro in some ways. Better to just "fix" the "problem", right?

Comment: @Houseman redesigning the entire rep system would be a herculean task and lord knows they have other, higher priorities right now.

Comment: @Houseman: Since the tool is public, it's relatively simple to detect it's use. Compared to the impossible task of "fixing" the system so it's __impossible__ to commit vote fraud, I think we're fine.

Comment: @Houseman Like I said; now that there are more eyes on it, devs can reverse engineer it, and build it into their own scripts for detection.  SE can even add it to the vote fraud script as well, without changing anything about what the perceived, "problem" is.  There are many solutions to this other than, "Oh, we didn't account for that.  Guess we have to throw it all out and start again!"

Comment: Oh, well good! As long as this is "detected" and makes the system a little more tamper-proof, then I'd say it's a net positive.

Comment: You mention PageRank here, and quite a lot on your GitHub page... But how would such a system work for SO? If it's the solution, surely you thought out some details on how it should function?

Comment: @Cerbrus hi, I don't have the exact algorithm yet due to lazyness, and any guess is useless without testing it out on real data. But I am confident that it is possible to create an algorithm where votes by high rep users will have more weight. Simplest idea is: users and answers are "pages", user upvotes answer is a link from user page to answer page. User writes answer is a link from answer to user page. Then direct PageRank on graph.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: A user's reputation isn't a good measure of their expertise in a random field. If I were to upvote a Haskell answer, my vote would carry significantly more weight compared than that of someone that actually knows anything about Haskell. That's not acceptable. You seem to think PageRank is the holy grail here, but I seriously doubt it's going to fix more problems than it would cause.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, I want to incorporate tags in the algorithm as well as mentioned at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/write-free-science-books-to-get-famous-website/tree/d77b18d2e7acb3558615797c36195f60dfd26306#pagerank-with-tags but I don't know exactly how to do it, and I'm at fault in that.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe something like: each user has one page per tag. Then make the previously mentioned graph only on answers to questions with a given tag. If you want a global user rep, create a global user node, and point all "user-tag" nodes to it.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you really think this PageRank idea through before suggesting it on here. Re-writing the voting system is a ___momentous___ undertaking, and really doesn't leave room for _"I haven't considered X yet"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes. The problem is that it can't be done at all without test data. I think it will never change, until something better beats SO.

Comment: Well then, if that's all, time to write something better.

Comment: Mods work really hard to stop voter fraud. I wish you hadn't done this. It makes the mods' jobs harder, and it is costing you the trust of the community. You make me sad.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 So what is your goal then? Are you trying to make Stack Exchange bad enough by polluting it with illegitimate reputation that it gets beat out by a competitor? This looks to me like you're just sabotaging the site intentionally and willfully because you don't like some aspects of it.

Comment: My ideas and thoughts are often in line with yours, but this time I disagree. IMO, security isn't the same as gaming a system where rules aren't so strictly enforced technically. Security is like breaching a system and SSHing into it, but gaming is more like enjoying every phone in the market without spending a single cent by returning them soon and get a refund. Sharing vote fraud scripts is similar to teaching people how to abuse the return policy, in which case your stand of "security by obscurity" doesn't make much sense.