# How can I write a good "About Me" on my profile?

Tags: discussion

What are the dos and don'ts for writing an "About Me" in my Stack Overflow profile?

Comment: Look at the "About Me"s of high-rep users for inspiration!

Comment: You also should really think about your privacy when it comes to write identifying data in there. This also includes your username and your avatar. When you have private data somewhere in your profile, when users can identify you in real life and you should ask yourself if you're comfortable with that. This also includes links to your own webpage, Twitter, Instagram or other social media.

Comment: Just don't write anything that violates the code of conduct, and pretty much everything is good. There's a large variety of "about me"'s

Comment: Lots of people put stuff about the license of SO.

Comment: Not gonna bother writing an answer for a number of reasons, but the first thing you need to ask yourself is, what do you want to get out of it? Do you want to promote yourself? An organization related or unrelated to you? Do you wanna introduce yourself? Or maybe something you're passionate about? Do you wanna bring attention to a cause you believe in? Your "about me" is your space, and you can do almost whatever you want with it (within the constraints of various rules of SO, though discarding advertising rules - to be clear, promoting yourself in a question or answer isn' always [1/2]¨

Comment: okay, but the "about me" can be purely meant to promote yourself without getting you into trouble). Like with other "about me"'s on the internet, you have a lot of options, and there's no rules for what an about me should look like, or what qualifies as a good about me - what defines a good "about me" is how well it lives up to what you wanna do with it. Don't worry too much about what you should and shouldn't put in there, and rather put what you want in it

Comment: Read code of conduct and that should be enough... Some previous discussion - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334578/acceptable-profile-photos,
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265206/linking-to-paypal-donate-in-your-about-me

Comment: I don't like repeating what's already established as reasonable convention, so [read this link from when Jaydles was still a CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231362/175248) about some dos and don'ts about profile entries.

Comment: I added some of my photography to mine. :)

Comment: ["Why is “primarily opinion-based” a valid close reason on Meta?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252237/why-is-primarily-opinion-based-a-valid-close-reason-on-meta) - Hint: it doesn't seem to be this

Answer (score 12):

#### Regarding the **Dos**:

There is a lot you can do with your profile. Some ideas are:

- Use it as a cover letter to attract potential employers or interesting connections.
- Use it to show off something creative.
- Tell your life story.
- Share your achievements.
- Talk about something random that excites you (*turtles?*)

If your question is asking about how to decorate your profile to make it look interesting to other users or a potential employer then I am afraid that your question is too opinion-based for meta (even with the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag). My general advice in that direction would be (as others said) to look at other peoples' profiles. And the general advice on how to write a profile online (there are [thousands of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+write+interestin+about+me&oq=how+to+write+interesting+about+me) on it).

Half of the interesting things on my profile, for example, are <s>stolen</s> *borrowed* from other profiles. ;)

#### Regarding the **Don'ts**:

This is where the lines get fuzzy and the question feels too broad to discuss. This is an online community with millions of users with different opinions and cultures. *Try* not to offend someone. But do note that anything vaguely controversial will probably offend someone. Heck, something that you never thought could be offensive might be perceived as such by someone else.

There are some obvious things though like **don't put anything illegal** on there (pornographic depictions of minors, links to sites selling illegal drugs, etc). That crap will be deleted and you might get a visit from your local authorities.

Following the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) is good advice but you can possibly *indirectly* "attack" a user and get away with it.

What is stopping you from attacking me in your profile saying:

> There is a certain user rooming around here on SO; he has a black silhouette for a profile picture. I think he has absolutely nothing to do in his life and is just completely full of himself.

I have seen some profiles on SO with "attacks" like these (with worse language of course). How can one say this is an attack directed at them *specifically*? It is open for debate. And probably needs to be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Now, things that are "disturbing" and "violent" are opinion-based and are also up for debate... A very good example of this is [Ciro Santilli's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%e9%83%9d%e6%b5%b7%e4%b8%9c%e5%86%a0%e7%8a%b6%e7%97%85%e5%85%ad%e5%9b%9b%e4%ba%8b%e4%bb%b6%e6%b3%95%e8%bd%ae%e5%8a%9f).

They write extensively about the Chinese government and its hypocrisy. Many people can find their references to the [Tiananmen massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Tiananmen_Square_protests) as being "too violent" or "not family-friendly". Does this mean that we should remove their profile? Aren't they using their profile as a voice to openly raise awareness about issues that take away their night's sleep? Well, I can guarantee you that the Chinese government will be more than happy to have their profile deleted.

There are already a lot of meta posts on both MSO and MSE on topics that relate to the about-page, profile picture, and username. You can easily find them.

### Beware:

*Think first, write later.*

There is also a valid concern about online privacy. Do you really want strangers online to know your email id, your phone number, your kids' ages? If you are fine with sharing this stuff then go ahead. But at least make sure that you familiarize yourself with the [risks involved](https://www.google.com/search?q=risks+of+sharing+personal+information+online). Any information that you upload should be considered permanently compromised. And you will be solely responsible for any problems that are caused because of it.

If you are going to put something highly controversial up there (something that a certain community feels rather strongly about) then it isn't really a bad idea to first consult your local laws and SE's policy on it (there should be a meta post or two, if not then ask). Also, you better be ready for handling criticism and attacks (even death threats in rare cases). You might have to invest your time and money into it.

SE has historically been lenient with the about-page of users. But remember that *SE is a company*. The things you put on your profile are *your* opinions. The moment SE starts feeling that hosting your opinions for you (for free I might add) is causing more harm than good, they won't be so keen on continuing doing that.

Note that companies change. Today they say something, tomorrow they might change their stance. Today they support (or at least tolerate) you, tomorrow they will delete your account. So, if you really want to say something controversial, then the SE about-page might not be your best bet.

Also, generally, when someone finds your about-page offensive they usually flag one of your posts (questions/answers/comments/chat messages) and ask a moderator to handle the situation. At these times you should at least try to be somewhat understanding of someone else's viewpoint. You might be able to come up with some mutual consensus on the issue that satisfies both parties (adding spoilers on NSFW images for example).

---

Lastly, there is no harm in leaving that page empty.